# How can I fix my HRLV-MaxSonar-EZ ultrasonic sensor so it does not give gibberish feedback?

Tags: sensors

I have hooked up my ultrasonic sensor to my Arduino correctly, I know this because I am getting feedback from it, but when I run this code:

`int mode = 2;
double distance; 
double calibration;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(12, INPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  if(mode == 1)
  {
  //Read duration in microSeconds
  long duration = pulseIn(12, HIGH);
  //58 uS per cm for MB1240 XL-MaxSonar
  //Operation Range: 20 cm min (50 cm for accurate)
  distance = duration / 58.0; 
  calibration = -20;
  }
  else if (mode == 2)
  {
  //Analog In .49 mV per unit 
  double voltage = analogRead(5)*.0049; 
 //.49 mV per cm;
  distance = voltage/.0049;
  calibration = 0.0;
  } 
  double cmToInch = 0.393701;
  //Analog Seems to be More Accurate due to PWM timing
  Serial.print((distance+calibration)*cmToInch);
  Serial.println(" in");
  delay(100);
}`

I get sporadic results when it is just sitting there without anything moving in front of, let alone around it at all:

[image: distance that I from my sensor]

What is wrong here? Is it my code, is the sensor just very sensitive, or is it something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, what is at 148 or so inches from the sensor?

Comment: That's exactly it, nothing is.

Comment: so absolutely nothing for 12 feet, not even a wall?

Comment: Nope, and it changes without anything around it moving; it was in the middle of an empty room. Also, it doesn't change much when I move my hand in front of it.

Comment: `voltage = analogRead(5)*.0049; distance = voltage/.0049` is just a long winded way of doing `distance = analogRead(5)` - I think your logic is messed up